# Kerberos not found when using node, mongodb, and watchify

Tags: node.js, macos, mongodb, npm, browserify

I'm having issues adding mongodb to an express app.

`npm install mongodb` gives this result:

```
> kerberos@0.0.12 install /Users/michael/Documents/heroku/node_viz/app/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/worker.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberosgss.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/base64.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos_context.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/kerberos.node
mongodb@2.0.42 node_modules/mongodb
├── readable-stream@1.0.31 (inherits@2.0.1, isarray@0.0.1, string_decoder@0.10.31, core-util-is@1.0.1)
├── es6-promise@2.1.1
└── mongodb-core@1.2.10 (bson@0.4.11, kerberos@0.0.12)
```

If I try to include mongodb using `var mongodb = require("mongodb");` and use watchify to bring everything together then I get a series of messages repeating:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/kerberos' from '/Users/michael/Documents/heroku/node_viz/app/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib'
Error: Cannot find module '../../../build/Release/kerberos' from '/Users/michael/Documents/heroku/node_viz/app/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/lib/win32/wrappers'
```

I've tried installing everything globally, everything locally, and installing mongoose globally and copying over the kerberos directory into a local mongodb node_module. I've even tried uninstalling node and mongodb completely and trying them with both homebrew and direct installs. I've tried everything I've been able to find and would love some suggestions. Thanks for the help!

Currently installed global packages:

- npm
- node-gyp
- watchify

Currently installed local packages:

- body-parser
- cookie-parser
- d3
- debug
- express
- jade
- morgan
- serve-favicon

Comment: Isn't `watchify` meant for `browserify` builds? I would guess that native modules won't work well in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the issue.

The source of the problem was trying to `require("mongodb")` in my client side javascript. I split my code into client and server side on separate ports and have them communicating via api with no issues.